# SAS - Find out if previous account id has been used in the past

Tags: sas

I'm trying to figure out if an account ID has been used before in the past within my dataset.

Primary_ID = Unique ID for user (users only get 1 primary ID). Regardless of how many accounts a user has they will all fall under the same Primary_ID
Acct_ID = Unique ID for account.
Transaction_DT = Date transaction occurred.

How can I find out if a user has transacted on an account in the past? For example; Primary_ID=001 has a transaction on 07OCT2022 for Acct_ID=101, but have they done one in the past? Just from observing the data, yes they did do a transaction before on Acct_ID=101 on 05JAN2020. Same can be said for Primary_ID=002. Not clear how I can do this through SAS and would appreciate the help.

| Primary_ID | Acct_ID | Transaction_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 101 | 05JAN2020 |
| 001 | 100 | 10MAY2021 |
| 001 | 103 | 15MAY2021 |
| 001 | 101 | 07OCT2022 |
| 002 | 110 | 23SEP2021 |
| 002 | 111 | 20DEC2021 |
| 002 | 110 | 03OCT2022 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great application of the SQL `having` clause.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select primary_id
             , acct_id
             , count(acct_id) as total_transactions
        from have
        group by primary_id, acct_id
        having count(acct_id) > 1
    ;
quit;
```

Output:

```
primary_id  acct_id total_transactions
001         101     2
002         110     2
```

If you wanted to get the exact dates where they made those transactions:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select primary_id, acct_id, date
        from have
        group by primary_id, acct_id
        having count(acct_id) > 1
    ;
quit;
```

Output:

```
primary_id  acct_id date
1           101     05JAN2020
1           101     07OCT2022
2           110     03OCT2022
2           110     23SEP2021
```

Comment: Hi Stu! Thanks for your response. My only hesitation with this method is that it would double-count transactions that happened on a same day too, which is not what I would want. So for example if I had Primary_ID=3 and acct_id=101 and there was two transactions done on the acct_id on 07OCT2022, then this method would capture this as 2. But my desire is to have this not captured at all since I only want to know if there was a previous transaction done.

Comment: In that case, I would consider removing duplicate transactions before querying: `proc sort data=have nodupkey; by primary_id acct_id date; run;` You may also be able to do `count(distinct date)` and get the same result.

Comment: Hmm okay I'll try the count(distinct date). Because technically these wouldn't be duplicates, they were diff transactions under the same account happening in the same day in the example I made in my reply. I forgot to include a unique transaction id.

Comment: Hey Stu just wanted to say thanks for the advice, it worked out great!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For the case of detecting an earlier date you can compare the groups aggregate `min()` to its `max()`, or use `range()`.  Example:

```
data have; input 
Primary_ID  Acct_ID Transaction_DT date9.;
format t: date9.;
datalines;
001 101 05JAN2020
001 100 10MAY2021
001 103 15MAY2021
001 101 07OCT2022
002 110 23SEP2021
002 111 20DEC2021
002 110 03OCT2022
003 120 03OCT2022
003 120 03OCT2022
003 120 03OCT2022
003 120 03OCT2022
003 121 01JAN2022
;

proc sql;
  create table want(label='prim+acct with transactions on more than one date') as
  select primary_id, acct_id
  from have
  group primary_id, acct_id
  having range(transaction_dt) > 0
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a flag showing which transactions are not the first for that `primary_id * acct_id` combination, you can use the code below. (NB - if there were 2 transactions on the same date, then this code would NOT flag them. If that causes a problem, you might consider using a datetime value instead of date.)

```
* create sample data;
data have; 
    input Primary_ID Acct_ID Transaction_DT date9.;
    format Transaction_DT date9.;
    datalines;
001 101 05JAN2020
001 100 10MAY2021
001 103 15MAY2021
001 101 07OCT2022
002 110 23SEP2021
002 111 20DEC2021
002 110 03OCT2022
;
run;

* use proc sql with GROUP BY and MIN() to check if earliest transaction;
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select have.*,
        case when transaction_dt ne min(transaction_dt) then 1 else 0 end as previous_transaction_flag
    from have
    group by primary_id, acct_id
    order by primary_id, acct_id, transaction_dt
    ;
quit;
```